JavaScript "element is not defined" in Array.prototype.find()
I am building an application in ReactJS that uses tags to organize photos.  My data structure is set up in three parts: (1) photos, (2) tags and (3) "imageTags" which are relationships between a photo and a tag.  For photos that have id's 9, 12, and 35 and have tags 4, 5, and 6 respectively, the imageTag object would look like this:
const imageTags = [
  {id: 1, imageId: 9, tagId: 4},
  {id: 2, imageId: 12, tagId: 5},
  {id: 3, imageId: 35, tagId: 6}
]

The "Tag" component is passed only the imageTag id, from which it should be able to determine the image it is assigned to, and the tag that should be on that image, like this:
// props: imagetagId={7}
const imageId = imageTags.find(element => element.id === props.imageTagId)

This works fine for initial render.  However, when a user tries to remove a tag from a photo,* the state of the app changes and suddenly I get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: element is undefined

What I don't understand is, how can "element" be undefined?  My understanding is that it is walking through the imageTags object and checking each "element", hence why I named the variable that way.  I know this is NOT an issue of "imageTags.find(...) is undefined", it is not that the find method is returning no results.  To me the error reads as if element itself is undefined... but how is that possible?
Here is the function that alters imageTags when a user tries to remove a tag:
// remove a specific imageTag from imageTags
const handleRemoveTag = (imageTagId) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(imageTags)) {
    if (value.id == imageTagId) {
      delete imageTags[key];
    };
  };
};

*another important detail I have found: this error does NOT occur when removing the LAST tag in the list.  Tags can be safely removed one at a time starting from the final one to the first one, but removing a tag from the middle or beginning causes this error.  I'm not sure why that would be, but it seems relevant for troubleshooting.

That imageTags declaration is not valid JavaScript.

Specifically, is it actually an array or is it whatever this is shown here?

I am simplifying a little bit for the sake of making the question easier to understand.  The ImageTags object is nested in an object that holds other data for the app, but when the relevant functions are called, only this piece is passed to them.  @RobbyCornelissen what makes it invalid JavaScript?  I may have just typo-ed it in this explanation, I can clarify if it doesn't make sense.

It's not a valid object declaration because it lacks keys. It's not a valid array declaration because it's using curly braces. So people don't know what you intend to use.

@RobbyCornelissen ah I see, yes that makes sense.  I've double-checked by code and it is an array of objects in the code, I've edited my question to reflect this.  Although, the handleRemoveTag function returns an object with key 0, like imageTags = {0: {id: 1 ...}, {id: 2}}  Could that discrepancy be the cause of the error I'm encountering?

Actually if you just delete a key from the array (and not changing the length or the likes) you'll easily encounter a similar error. For example: let a = [1,2]; delete a[a.length-1]; a.find(element=>element.key). Here, a.length is still 2 but a[1] gives you undefined.

Why can’t imageTags be an Array?
const imageTags = [               // <—-
  {id: 1, imageId: 9, tagId: 4},  //    |
  {id: 2, imageId: 12, tagId: 5}, //    |—- Array of Objects.
  {id: 3, imageId: 35, tagId: 6}  //    |
]                                 // <—-
To remove a specific imageTag from imageTags if it is an Array, use this procedure.
const handleRemoveTag = (imageTagId) => {
  let index = imageTags.findIndex(element => element.id === imageTagId)
  imageTags.splice(index, 1)
}

I tried this quickly just now and I am getting the same error.  I will try again tomorrow when I have more time to tease out any potential pitfalls that I might be missing.  When I console.log(ImageTags), it says "Array," so it may be set up as you have it, but when I console.log(typeof ImageTags) it says "object," so I'm not positive.  I can take a more detailed look at it soon and get back to you on it.

An Array is an Object. Test Array.isArray instead.

Can confirm, it is an array not a dictionary.  I've updated my question to reflect how the code is actually set up.  However I've noticed that the result returned by the handleRemoveTag function is a dict, like {0: {id:1 ...}, {id: 2...}}  Could that be the cause of this error?  Is that being caused by me trying to use Object.entries, and does your solution fix that?  (Trying this now to see if I can answer these questions myself with the code)

Since you have made imageTags an Array like I advised, why are you still using Object.entries on it? Why not use the Array interface? I shared a possible implementation in my answer didn't I? Use it.

I've put in your implementation.  (Sorry for the delay, this is a personal project and I only have small bits of time to put to it.)  I am seeing the same behavior as described in the original question, I can delete tags starting from the last assigned to an image and safely go backwards that way, but if I try to delete the first tag that was assigned to an image before deleting the last, the whole thing crashes.

After playing around a bit more with this, I got something to work based off your answer!  Thank you for your help with this!
